# Crystal report make string bold

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, bold

I need to make the first string in this formula bold, can anyone help with this?

I am posting below a single fragment of the formula first and after the full formula including the fragment, appreciate all the help.

string in question:

```
if ({IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.cardname}) <> "" then 
    InvAddr:=InvAddr + chr(13) + {IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.cardname} + ChrW(13) ;
```

full formula:

```
  WhilePrintingRecords;
Local StringVar InvAddr;
InvAddr:="";

if ({IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.cardname}) <> "" then 
    InvAddr:=InvAddr + chr(13) + {IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.cardname} + ChrW(13) ; 

if not isnull({IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.address}) then
    InvAddr:=InvAddr + {IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.address} + ChrW(13); 
//if not isnull({IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.VatNo}) then
//    InvAddr:=InvAddr + 'VAT No:'+{IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.VatNo}; 


//Add EORI Number
if ({IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.BPEORINumber}) <> "" then
    InvAddr:=InvAddr + chr(13) + "EORI No.: " + {IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.BPEORINumber}; 


//Add VAT Number
if ({IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.vatno}) <> "" then
    InvAddr:=InvAddr + chr(13) + "VAT No.: " + {IIS_EPC_EML_MDOC.vatno}; 

//Strip out trailing blank spaces from address block
while instr(InvAddr," "+Chr(13)) > 0 do
(
    InvAddr:=Replace(InvAddr," "+Chr(13),Chr(13));
);

//Strip out blank lines from address block
while instr(InvAddr,Chr(13)+Chr(13)) > 0 do
(
    InvAddr:=Replace(InvAddr,Chr(13)+Chr(13),Chr(13));
);
 
InvAddr
```

best Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

One option is to construct the text as HTML with bold text where you desire.
Then, right-click the formula,
select ***Format Field...***
Select '***Paragraph***' tab
and set 'Text Interpretation' to 'HTML text'.

Comment: Hi MiletSoftware, that will work but i only want a small portion of the code to be bold not all. Best Regards,Daniel

Comment: Enclose only that bold portion with the html tags to make it bold.